# Display a tableView over another view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I would like to achieve a similar effect:

http://imageshack.us/m/695/3715/img0419s.png

My initial idea was to create something like presentend in this schema http://imageshack.us/m/9/9227/img0413.png. Ie a ViewController with 2 subviews: a classical one with some information, and a tableView below which should scroll over the previous view.

But I realized that dividing the main view this way couldn't allow my tableview to scroll over the first view.

So I'm asking how this effect is possible. Maybe by setting a transparent header ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the teriiehina's advise, here is how I dit it :

In my UITableViewController, I set a 50px contentInset and a transparent color to my tableView.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,0,0,0);
```

I added an additional view on the top of the view (same size than the contentInset)

```
TTView *test = [[TTView alloc] init];
test.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
test.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:test];
```

Finally, in order to let my tableview scroll over the additional view, I brought it in the front

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.tableView];
```

Now I just have to set a custom color for my cells.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty trick here:

1. Add the `UIView` that contains the name first
2. Add a `UIScrollView` with `clipBounds = NO`. That view will contain the message.

That should work for you

Comment: I can't find the property `clipBounds` on the Apple documentation.

What's its purpose ?

Comment: It's called clip Subviews in Interface Builder. When set to off it will allow the contents to be shown even when they would be outside the bounds of the View

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll also try this way and let you know !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this effect using the contentInset property of the UITableView (which is a UIScrollView subclass) and presenting the tableView at first with a programmatic scroll.

Comment: Add a padding around the tableView. Good idea, I'll try that next monday ;)